# laravel undefined variable

Tags: laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять почему он не видит переменную menu

Comment: Проверьте саму переменую что в ней. Она может быть пустая приходит

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу выше вы пробуете ее вызвать и она не дает ошибку, попробуйте так

```
{{ $menu == "contacts" ? 'light' : '' }}
```

если ошибка сохранится проверьте имя то есть скопируйте с предыдущего вызова.